# Load PNG images to array and use as textures

Tags: arrays, unity-game-engine, texture2d

I've been attempting to use PNG images as textures in Unity, when I use only one or two its easy to drag and drop them in the inspector. In my current project I have over 300 images which I am trying to load into an array, I then want to change the texture each time round the update so it appears like a video.

Here is what I have so far:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class ChangeImage : MonoBehaviour {

public Texture[] frames;
public int CurrentFrame;
public object[] images;

    void OnMouseDown() {
        if (GlobalVar.PlayClip == false){
            GlobalVar.PlayClip = true;          
        } else {
            GlobalVar.PlayClip = false;         
        }
    }   

    public void Start() {

        images = Resources.LoadAll("Frames");

        for (int i = 0; i < images.Length; i++){
            Texture2D texImage = (Texture2D) images[i];
            frames[i] = texImage;
        }
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        if(GlobalVar.PlayClip == true){
            CurrentFrame++;
            CurrentFrame %= frames.Length;
            GetComponent<Renderer>().material.mainTexture = frames[CurrentFrame];
        }
    }   


}
```

I have been attempting to load the images into an object array convert them to textures then output to a texture array. Does anyone know where I am going wrong with this it does not seem to give any errors but the texture is not changing?

Any advice is much appreciated

Thanks

Comment: note that animations *and indeed video* is perfectly built-in to Unity

Comment: purely FWIW, note also. it's inconceivable you'd want to move through an animation every *Unity frame* (ie, as you would theoretically be doing using `Update` there)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix the problem eventually, the problem seemed to be the loading of assets was not working correctly and this was why the frame was not changing. I also changed the name of the folder containing the images from "Frames" to "Resources". Here is the completed code for anyone else who needs it:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class ChangeImage : MonoBehaviour {

public Texture[] frames;
public int CurrentFrame;

    void OnMouseDown() {
        if (GlobalVar.PlayClip == false){
            GlobalVar.PlayClip = true;          
        } else {
            GlobalVar.PlayClip = false;         
        }
    }   

    public void Start() {
        frames = Resources.LoadAll<Texture>("");
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        if(GlobalVar.PlayClip == true){
                CurrentFrame %= frames.Length;
                CurrentFrame++;
                Debug.Log ("Current Frame is " + CurrentFrame);
                GetComponent<Renderer>().material.mainTexture = frames[CurrentFrame];               
            }

        }

}
```

Thanks for the advice on animations I will still look into it as the performance of the images is not great.

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing is kinda slow and inappropriate.

What I would recommend is to use the Animator and an animation. Have all your textures into a atlas texture, this way you will limit the draw call amount. Make that texture a sprite and use the sprite editor to cut in sub sprite.

Add an animator and create an animation. Select the whole sub sprites and drag them into the animation. Done.

Now you can easily control the speed and the playing via the animator component.

Comment: Thanks, can I ask do animations maintain transparency all my PNG images have the background removed?

Comment: Of course they do. http://michaelcummings.net/mathoms/creating-2d-animated-sprites-using-unity-4.3